# How to make a countdown with input field with how many minutes the countdown must go?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, countdown

I have made a countdown but now I want to make a input field with how many minutes the countdown should countdown from. What I have is a pretty basic countdown but what I don't have is that a user puts the amount of minutes into the input field, click the button, and it counts down the minutes. And I hope someone can help me with this.

This is what I got so far:

```js
    (()=> {
     let countdownEnded = false;
    start(3600); // seconds
    })();

        function start(inputTime){
        let startTime = Date.now();
        intervalSeconds = setInterval(() => {
            let currentTime = Date.now() - startTime;

            if(inputTime < 1) {
                stop(); 
            } else {
                updateDisplay(inputTime, currentTime);
                updateMillis();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }


    function stop(){
        let countDivElement = document.getElementById("countdown");  /*** Updated***/  
        countDivElement.innerHTML = 'countdown done';
        countdownEnded = true;   /*** Updated***/  
    }

    function updateDisplay(seconds, currentTime){    
        let timeIncrement = Math.floor(currentTime / 1000);
        updateTime(seconds - timeIncrement);
    }

    /**
     * @method - updatesecondsond
     * @summary - This updates the timer every seconds
     */
    function updateTime(seconds) {
        let countDivElement = document.getElementById("timer");

        let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        let remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        
        
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = '0' + remainingSeconds;
        }

        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }
        
        if (seconds > 0) {      
            seconds = seconds - 1;
        } else {
            clearInterval(intervalSeconds);
            countdownEnded = true;
            countDivElement.innerHTML = 'countdown done';
            return null;
        }

        countDivElement.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds + ":" ;
    };

    function updateMillis() {
        let countMillsElement = document.getElementById('millis');
        let counterMillis = 99;
        let millis;

        let intervalMillis = setInterval(()=> {

        if(counterMillis === 1) {
            counterMillis = 99;
        } else {
            millis = counterMillis < 10 ? '0' + counterMillis : counterMillis;
        };

        countMillsElement.innerHTML = millis;
        counterMillis --;

        }, 10);

        if(countdownEnded) {
        stop();              /*** Updated***/  
        return clearInterval(intervalMillis);
        }
    };
```

```html
  <div class="clock" id="model3">
    <div id="countdown">    <!-- Updated -->  
      <span id="timer"></span><span id="millis"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input id="minutes" placeholder="0:00"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a button with click event that takes input value and triggers your 'start' function with that value as parameter. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("startBtn").addEventListener("click", startTimer);
function startTimer() {
  var numberOfMinutes = Number(document.getElementById("minutes").value) * 60;
  start(numberOfMinutes);
}
```

And remove 'start' function call from the window load to prevent the timer to start immidiately.
Result is something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/scarabs/6patc9mo/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you.
Change the following

```
<input id="minutes" placeholder="00"/>  <button onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
```

And in javascript add a new function

```
function startTimer(){
var x=document.getElementById("minutes").value * 60; //To Change into Seconds
start(x);
}
```

And remove the start function